# How much of the book does the movie Dune (2021) cover?

Tags: dune, dune-2021

I've read like... 100 pages of the book. How much more should I read before watching *Dune (2021)*, so that the movie does not spoil anything from the book for me?

Comment: The page numbers shouldn't be relied on as there were/are different editions. Have you reached the fight with Jamis?

Comment: my advice is read the whole book then watch the film. That way you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Till where I have read, the family has just arrived on Akkaris.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. that's pretty bad advice. You only need to read Dune to understand the film, and you only need to read the first three books to fully understand Paul.

Comment: On the contrary, the last three give a perspective of Paul (the limits of his vision, the choices he made) that's missing from the first three (if, as I do, you see the son as an extension of the father). That being said, I was following on from skyjack's comment - my comment is an extension of the issue, conversational and doesn't stick to the point of the question. @OrangeDog

Comment: Hard to say without spoilers... About half seems right. There's a point in the book where about 3 years are skipped over. That's about where the movie ends.

Comment: Follow @skyjack's advice, then be disappointed by the movie. (Based on the general experience that the movies are never as good as the book. Haven't read the book or watched the movie. _ducks_)

Comment: @FreeMan surprisingly this movie deviates from the norm, and it's both pretty faithful to the book and a good movie. A pretty great adaptation.

Answer (score 12):

There's a page-break just after the paragraphs below*. A guy called Jamis has just been killed and Paul and his mother are heading off to a sietch with Stilgar and his band.

> Stilgar held up a hand, and there was silence. “As to Jamis,” he said, “I order the full ceremony. Jamis was our companion and brother of the Ichwan Bedwine. There shall be no turning away without the respect due one who proved our fortune by his tahaddi-challenge. I invoke the rite . . . at sunset when the dark shall cover him.”
>
> Paul, hearing these words, realized that he had plunged once more into
> the abyss . . . blind time. There was no past occupying the future in
> his mind . . . except . . . except . . . he could still sense the
> green and black Atreides banner waving . . . somewhere ahead . . .
> still see the jihad’s bloody swords and fanatic legions.
>
> It will not be, he told himself. I cannot let it be.
>
> **= = = = = =**

That's pretty much where the film ends and most everything beyond this point is going to appear [in the sequel](https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2022/03/denis-villeneuve-on-how-dune-survived-the-upheaval-of-hollywood).

> The success means we get to make the second movie, which means we’ll
> be able to complete the second half of Herbert’s novel. That film will
> debut exclusively in theaters. It’s part of the deal.

<sub><sup>*For those listening along on an unabridged audiobook version, that would be approximately 59% of the way through. In the [George Guidall audiobook](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Frank-Herbert-Narrated-George-Guidall/dp/1402523807), for example, this scene occurs at ***13:41:50***</sup></sub>

Comment: Jeez .. Thanks for ruining Jamis' plot lines  for me.  Where are the spoiler tags /s

Comment: @PeterM - If you were expecting him to kill the poster character from a multi-film tentpole franchise, you may need to reset your expectation of how Hollywood works

Comment: I believe that your answer while being factually correct is also highly undesirable for OP. He states that he does not want to be spoiled by a movie and you are revealing important parts of plot that lies ahead of him. I think the answer OP wants should be vague, perhaps even not clear until he reads enough pages to safely watch the movie .

Comment: @Diegogo - I was quite careful not to tell him who killed Jamis. Also, it's a pretty anti-climactic place to end the film anyway.

Comment: @Valorum Seems I imputed to much of my own knowledge into your answer. After second thought I agree , that it is vague enough.

Comment: And fwiw, Jamis is a character the the audience meets about 10 minutes before he [Jamis] meets his...fate. Also, without some deft reading of the context clues in the quote above, there is nothing in Valorum's answer that ** specifically ** says what happened to Jamis. - pretty sure the /s in @PeterM's comment == 'sarcasm'

Comment: @NKCampbell - Just be thankful that I didn't spoil the fact that Jamis turns out to be Paul's real father.

Comment: well yeah - it's the entire underlying conceit of not just the first book but the other two books in the opening trilogy as well. Not something you want to spoil for sure

Comment: @NKCampbell Apparently I need to explicitly spell it out /s

Comment: @Diegogo Although, for the record, it is Paul who kills Jamis.

Comment: @Lexible - Janis is killed by hubris. Paul is merely fate's instrument.

Comment: @Valorum Pretty sure *hubris* is also fate's instrument. (C.f., guns don't kill people: bullets kill people, etc.)

Comment: I think it's climatic in the book, but excites your imagination about where it's going ... the movie kind of glossed some details that would have added to the climax. It's one of my favorite parts.

Comment: Interestingly, the book is split into three "books". This isn't even where the second book ends and really isn't anything of a climax

Comment: I was just coming back to say that. I'm rereading it and just noticed yesterday. "Book 1" ends a few scenes before this fight, and a cliffhanger, I would say.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to give an answer that risks no spoilers...

It's very hard to say where in the book the 2021 movie ends without spoilers, but about half seems right. There's a point in the book where about 3 years are skipped over. That's about where the movie ends. Edging close to spoilers, some significant conflict between the Atredies and Harkkonens occurs just before this break in story timeline. It's really no spoiler that there will be this conflict eventually. Numerous pages are spent discussing its inevitability.

*Dune* is actually already divided into 3 "books". By that measure, the movie ends just a small way through the second book, "Muad'dib". For contemporary Hollywood tastes, the demarcation between book 1 and 2 is far too nuanced to end a script. It signals a significant change in Paul of which the gravity would be hard to capture on film. But, there is a scene just into the second book that does give a decent ending for a Hollywood script, and that is where it ends.