# How much of the book does the movie "Dune: Part Two" (2024) cover?

Tags: dune, dune-2024

In terms of the original book, how much does *Dune: Part Two* cover?

I have finished the contents of the first movie (in the book *Dune*) and want to read the book and then watch the second movie, but without accidentally spoiling myself by reading too far on.

Something like a quote or a page number showing where the film finishes in the book would be nice.

Comment: It covers the parts of the book the first movie doesn't? There's not going to be a Part 3 (but maybe an adaptation of Dune Messiah)

Comment: The movie and the book are different experiences addressing different senses.  The plot is the least interesting part of both.

Comment: @fez Only if you know the answer. Nothing in principle to stop the movie covering less then the remaining novel leaving space for a third film, or going on in to the material of Dune Messiah. I don't think the answer is hard to find, but the question is defined.

Comment: Related, not dupe: ***[How much of the book does the movie Dune (2021) cover?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/259758/how-much-of-the-book-does-the-movie-dune-2021-cover)***

Comment: Related to Michael's point: the first season of *The Expanse* covered about 2/3 of the first book. The second season covered the rest of the first book and some amount of the second book. It wasn't until the third season that the end of a season corresponded to the end of a book.

Comment: Yep, Expanse was the recent example I had in mind.

Comment: @fez - Hollywood is not above making even [very short novels into trilogies](https://www.forbes.com/sites/briansolomon/2012/07/26/the-hobbit-as-a-trilogy-hollywood-has-jumped-the-shark/)

Comment: I should think is is a duplicate as this question's answered in the last paragraph of Valorum's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Villeneuve has stated on several occasions that *Dune, Part II* completes his adaptation of *[Dune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune_(novel))* by Frank Herbert. The first film spoils [the first half of the book](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/259758/how-much-of-the-book-does-the-movie-dune-2021-cover) and the second film covers/spoils the entire rest of *Dune*.

> **Q. Yes, exactly, triumphs… and it’s so dark and the way it ends. I mean, now you have to make that, and you have to make it next! You can’t leave us hanging like this [Laughs].**
>
> **Villeneuve:** *It’s true that I feel that the movie is complete, that the adaption of the book is now completed, but it’s true that myself as a filmmaker, I’m like, ‘It would make sense to go back one last time, and to finish the arc of Paul Atreides and Chani.’ It would make absolutely sense, yeah.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Denis Villeneuve Calls ‘Dune: Part Two’ A “Dark Tragedy,” Talks Potential ‘Messiah’ Sequel & More](https://theplaylist.net/denis-villeneuve-calls-dune-part-two-a-dark-tragedy-interview-20240228/)</sup></sub>

He's very clear that the next movie in the series would be an adaptation of [*Dune Messiah*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune_Messiah).

> “I think you cannot avoid Paul’s terrible purpose, that’s the
> structure of this whole enterprise. Saying this, I do not like to
> comment on Dune Messiah because I’m writing it, and when I’m writing,
> I love to shut up because it’s a very delicate time where things are
> fragile, ideas evolve. I like to talk about movies when they are
> alive, finished, and strong enough to walk by themselves. Dune Messiah
> is barely an embryo.”
>
> <sub><sup>[“Things Are Fragile”: Dune 3 Gets Cautious Update From Denis Villeneuve As Part 2 Hits Big](https://screenrant.com/dune-3-movie-update-future-denis-villeneuve-response/)</sup></sub>

Comment: "spoils"? Personal opinion or typo?

Comment: @VBartilucci - In this sense; "*a description of an important plot development in a television show, film, or book which if previously known may reduce surprise or suspense for a first-time viewer or reader.*"